# How to prepare a large txt File to batch insert using Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Im trying to insert over 200k rows to sql database, each row represent a card info(70+ string field). Within a Large TXT File.
I'm (new Java Developer) facing a quite hard time in this, My approach:

1. read File

```
    File file = ReadFile.loadCardFile(pathName);
```

2. convert File to stream

```
Stream<String> cardsStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), ("UTF-8"))).lines());
```

3. get each line in string array (the card info splitted by '|' and may or maynot that field is spaced)

```
cardsStream.forEach(s -> {
                    String[] card = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\|")).map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new);
```

4. insert each line (card data)

```
numberOfRows = insertCardService.setCard(card, numberOfRows);
```

5. setCard is to map row data to its columns then I save each card

```
CardService.save(Card);
```

with this approach it takes up to 2h which is really really **Long time**

Is there any advice to better approach or could you provide me with links to read code it better?

oh btw I want to use batch insert to shorten time significantly but I think my way of reading the file is wrong!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do some timing of the various operations. I'll be surprised if the DB insert time doesn't dominate.

Comment: @tgdavis that's true it take 95% of the entire time operation

Comment: Probably not worth worrying about how you read the file then. You could do batching, also what about dropping the indexes from the table and recreating them after you've finished the upload?

Comment: I don't get what you mean "about dropping the indexes from the table and recreating them after you've finished the upload?" part, heres how I create the object before the save maybe it'll clarify 
``` NICard Card = new NICard(
                    cards[Index.info1.getIndex()],
                    cards[Index.info2.getIndex()],
                    cards[Index.info3.getIndex()],
     .,
     ...~72)
```
     then
```
     CardService.save(Card);
```

Comment: Index.info.getIndex is from enum

Comment: Do you have a database administrator you can talk to?

Comment: @tgdavies unfortunately not atm as all having holiday, but appreaciate your response alot. =)

Comment: Are you saving card one by one? Instead of that just do insert them in batches, it will definitely save your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA is the wrong tool for this kind of operation.
While it is probably possible to make it fast with JPA it is unnecessary difficult to do this.
JPA works best in a workflow where you load some entities, edit some attributes and let JPA figure out which exact updates are necessary.
For this JPA does a lot of caching which might cost considerable resources.

But here it seems you just want to pump some relevant amount of data into the database.
You don't need JPA to figure out what to do, it's all insert.
You don't need JPAs cache.

I recommend Springs `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.
This probably already speeds up things considerable.

Once that works consider the following:

- Batch inserts, i.e. sending just one statement to the database. See https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/ Note that some database need special driver argument to properly handle batch updates.
- Doing intermittent commits. In general commits cost performance, because it forces databases to actually write data. But to long transaction might cause trouble as well, especially when the database is doing other stuff as well and in case of errors/rollbacks.
- You need more control over your batches, take a look at [Spring Batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch).

Answer (score 1):

By default hibernate will not save data in batches. You can enable that by setting below params.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```